# Chakra-UI useOutsideClick not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, chakra-ui

I'm having trouble making [`useOutsideClick()`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/hooks/use-outside-click) work properly.

It seems that when you click "below" the `<html>` the callback does not fire:

```
const ref = useRef();

const onClickOutside = () => {
  console.log("Clicked outside!");
};

useOutsideClick({
  ref,
  handler: onClickOutside
});

return (
  <Box p="4">
    <Text border="1px solid" mb="10" ref={ref}>
      When you click outside me a message should show up on the console.
    </Text>
    <Text border="1px solid">Try clicking me and then somewhere below.</Text>
  </Box>
);
```

If you click below the second `<Text>` tag, the callback is not fired. If you click anywhere else on page, the callback works as expected.

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the hook or if I'm actually missing something.

You can try it yourself on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-ui-useoutsideclick-hook-j66d2?file=/src/app.js:135-561).

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but useOutsideClick almost certainly adds an event handler to the document object. How would it be able to capture anything if the click is outside of the DOM (in your case, below the last text box)?

Comment: @BrendanBond just tried manually adding an `onclick` handler to the `<html>` and it works as expected. It doesn't matter if `<html>` height is 10px and you click below it, the `onclick` handler fires as expected.

Comment: click below second Text = click outside document body

Comment: Interesting! Looking at the [source for the chakra-ui hook](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/hooks/src/use-outside-click.ts), it has a function `isValidEvent` that tests for `if (target) { const doc = getOwnerDocument(target); if (!doc.body.contains(target)) return false; }` - though `doc` is almost certainly the document object, maybe for some reason the author wanted to make sure the click event was contained within the `body` element?

Comment: The JavaScript Window object is the highest level JavaScript object which corresponds to the web browser window. The document object is the container for all HTML HEAD and BODY objects associated within the HTML tags of an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, If you click outside the HTML element, you are kind of not even clicking *inside* the document. Event listeners are a property of the document, so then... if you're outside of the document, it would make sense that you don't trigger any effect on it, right?

I hope my answer will still be useful to you

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp